# How do I interface my Samsung Rugby II phone with Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, samsung, phone

I have a Samsung Rugby II phone, which I charge by plugging into the USB port.  It has pictures and video on it, which I'd like to get out through the USB port, but nothing pops up in Ubuntu when I plug it in.

When I plug it in, the phone presents a menu asking me to select the USB mode.  The choices are "Media Player", "PC Studio", and "Mass Storage".

If I select "Media Player", the response to lsusb in Ubuntu is:

Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04e8:5a0f Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Meizu M6 MiniPlayer

If I select "PC Studio", lsusb says:

Bus 001 Device 011: ID 04e8:6810 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd

If I select "Mass Storage", nothing is ever presented according to lsusb, and the phone is stuck in a prompt asking me to "Insert Memory Card".  I don't have a memory card in the phone (or at all), but the phone does have some sort of non-volatile memory (it keeps a bunch of photos and videos perfectly well without an additional card).

Does anyone know how to get the pics and vids I took out of it in Ubuntu without having to MMS them to myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem with my Rugby 2 phone. The phone needs a memory card before it can be interfaced your computer. The card has to be bought separately and is placed behind the battery in the phone back. There is no indication of this either on the phone or, in my case, in the owner's manual; I had to go to the place whee I bought the phone to learn about this. You can send photos and other data directly from the phone to a phone address and to an email address with out a memory card.

Comment: It appears to me that this may be true.  In addition to requiring a memory card, I had to edit /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf to change the line DisableSwitching=1 to DisableSwitching=0.

Comment: Actually, this works perfectly well on my work computer, but I still get no access on my home computer.